# Wine doesn't work (Problem with the mount manager)

Tags: 12.04, wine

I didn't know exactly when the problem occurred. My Wine worked well a couple days ago.
Then, I was just about to install some Windows programs hours ago but I got nothing.
No installer window showed up, and no error report. It just won't work. 
And now I just found where the problem is (screenshot below), but I don't know how to fix it.
Any idea? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image: Wine configuration]

Details:

- Wine 1.4
- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I tried:

- Autoremove in Terminal
- Delete the software configuration

Comment: By "delete the software configuration", do you mean that you deleted Wine's config directory? (`~/.wine`)

Comment: Yes. By that, I was wanting to install a new clean Wine with a new configuration. I also cleared the apt cache, so when I try to re-install Wine, the apt was downloading a new fresh package from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem is just a several bugs, and have been fixed with the latest `wine` update. No more responds are necessary, and thank you very much.